# Error when using imaginary number "i" in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I need to plot the following function with pgfplots in LaTeX, so the absolute value of the following image.

```
|e^{-ix(4+2)}\cdot \frac{2\sin(\frac{x(4-2)}{2})}{x}|
```

[image: 1]]

I tried the following code, but that ends in an error, that the function "i" is unknown.

```
\addplot [black,domain=-10:10, samples = 20, thick]{abs(exp(-i*x(4-2))*(2*sin(x*(4-2)/2))/x)};
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: What type of plot are you expecting to get, the values will be complex so do you want something in 3d?  As far as I know `pgfplots` and the math engine do not know about complex numbers.  You should write out the real and imaginary parts separately.

Comment: Oh i forget to add "abs" around everything.
Still doesn't work.

Comment: Well, so pgfplots doesn't do complex numbers. Bummer. But the exponential function of an imaginary argument has absolute value 1, so just go ahead and delete the whole exponential.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide complete (non)-compilable code for a minimal example rather than just a code fragment. It makes it much easier to help and much easier for other people to understand your question.

Comment: Keep in mind that pgfmath is a dancing bear.  The amazing thing is that it works at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you don't need to use complex numbers here at all: realising that `abs(exp(-i*x*(4-2)))=1` for all real `x`, you can just plot the absolute value of the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function). Note that you will want to set the option `trig format=rad`, otherwise the result will be unexpected as the default angular unit used by TikZ is degrees:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[trig format=rad]
\addplot[black,domain=-10:10,samples=200,thick]{abs((2*sin(x*(4-2)/2))/x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled plot]

Comment: Wow sometimes you may want to think one second about your formula and the plot it...
Thank you!